# How can I program with HTML and CSS Parallax Scrolling

Tags: html, css

I want to program something really specific, but I don't know how to describe it. I found a website which has what I want. It is http://www.sitetogo.nl.

When you scroll down, you'll see pictures that stay at their place and the textfields go upwards. But if you scroll further, the picture changes!!

Anyone any idea how to program??

Thank you!

Brent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is know as **Parallax Scrolling** you can see [w3schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp) or you can see this [tutorial](https://www.script-tutorials.com/bootstrap-one-page-template-with-parallax-effect/) as how to achieve that with bootstrap, because sitetogo is also using bootstrap.

Comment: Okay, thank you! And how can I switch from picture then? Like they did at sitetogo.nl?

Comment: See the tutorial, if you have a little bit of HTML and CSS knowledge you can do that.